# Even when giving proper shape for slicing I am getting a weird shape

Tags: python, numpy, slice, numpy-slicing

I am working on using a filter on an image in python and when I am iterating through the loop and slicing the image. I am not able to broadcast the numpy array due to different shapes. I have tried experimenting with different dimensions in my slicing but I can't seem to find what the issue is. I have even used various multiply functions so can't seem to understand how should I fix it.

```
filtered = np.zeros((len(img),(len(img[0]))))
image_slice = np.zeros((3,3))

for i in range(len(img)):
    for j in range(len(img[0])):
        image_slice = grayscale[0:3][j:j+3]

        s=np.multiply(W,image_slice)
        val = np.sum(s)
        filtered[i][j]=val
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-fbd48b449d58> in <module>
      6         image_slice = grayscale[i:i+3][j:j+3]
      7 
----> 8         s=np.multiply(W,image_slice)
      9         val = np.sum(s)
     10         filtered[i][j]=val

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (3,275)
```

Comment: try `grayscale[0:3, j:j+3]`

Comment: I have tried and this is the output I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: I assumed `grayscale` was a numpy array.  If it's a list then neither this nor your attempt works.

Comment: grayscale is a numpy array only ,it's still not working

Comment: Since I know nothing about `grayscale`, I prefer to believe the interpreter and error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.